# Doubt about the proof of $V_\omega\models\mathsf{Separation}$

Tags: set-theory

In Kunen's 'set theory', he introduce following theorem:

> Suppose that for each formula $\phi(x,z,\vec{w})$ with no variable besides the displayed ones free,$$\forall z, \vec{w}\in M:\{x\in z:\phi ^M(x,z,\vec{w})\}\in M$$
>   then the comprehension axiom (i.e. each instance thereof) is true in $M$.

But I think that we cannot use above proposition to prove $V_\omega\models \mathsf{Separation}$. Because, since axiom of separation is a axiom schema, we *may* have a Gödel numbering of nonstandard instance of separation (let it call $c$) and above theorem does not give the way to prove $V_\omega\models c$. Furthermore, above theorem is a not a theorem, but a theorem schema so it does not give a finitistic proof of $V_\omega\models\mathsf{Separation}$.

Is my argument correct? If not, I want to know the reason. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, this does not prove that your model believes that $V_\omega$ satisfies separation. Nonetheless it is true (by induction _inside_ the model). Also, it is true that $V_\omega$ regarded as a model in the meta-theory satisfies separation.

Comment: Could you give a page number for where Kunen claims that $V_\omega\vDash Separation$ follows from the lemma you quoted?

Comment: @GME page 113 in chapter IV.

Comment: @tetori I can't see that claim on p.113.

Comment: @GME When is published your book? My book is published in 1992.

Comment: @tetori Yep, that's the one I've got. I see the lemma (2.5) you mention. But not the claim that $V_\omega \vDash Separation$ in the non-schematic sense.

Answer (score 5):

If $T$ is a theory in some language $L$ and $M$ is an $L$-structure, the expression $M \models T$ is an abbreviation for, "for each $\phi \in T$, $M \models \phi$". So when Kunen writes $V_{\omega} \models \text{Comprehension}$, he intends it to be an abbreviation (in the finitistic meta theory) for saying that $V_{\omega}$ models each instance of comprehension scheme.

Comment: I think it is not an answer of my question. I already know that point.

Comment: My exact question is: $\varphi$ in the statement given by Kunen is meta-theoretic object. However, the right side of satisfaction relation $\models$ has "coded statement via natural number". However, we do not certain that every natural numbers in our set-theoretic universe is standard (more precisely, every natural number in our universe correspondences meta-theoretic natural number) Since separation axioms are axiom scheme, it may generates "non-standard axiom" in our universe. (cont.)

Comment: So if we want to argue $M\models \mathrm{separation}$, we must prove that $M\models\varphi$ for every instances $\varphi$ of separation schema whether $\varphi$ is standard or not.

Comment: There is no coding going on here. You are misinterpreting $V_{\omega} \models$ separation.